# How would one change the value of one integer to another?

Tags: python, integer

If, for simulation purposes, it was essential that a compiler took the value of one integer and in its stead used another value when doing some sort of calculation, how would the value of that integer be altered?
I have found various answers on setting the value of a variable to that of another, but I don't believe it would be possible to use the same concepts to achieve the desired result. I am also aware that this may not be achievable at all as it is would probably be necessary to tweak with the language or the compiler or something.
If it is possible, however, by doing something like hard-coding a value, how would that be done?

I have tried an extremely basic approach, but it has obviously failed: `3 = random.randint(60,900000)`.

Comment: Can you please explain your specific use-case?

Comment: Your use case does not benefit from what you are asking for in any way whatsoever.

Comment: Your use case doesn't make sense on its own, for that matter. It's not clear what role the entered value is supposed to serve, or what the output is actually supposed to depend on, or how this is supposed to be superior to traditional RNGs.

Comment: "The number returned would be more 'random' than anything possible with a regular pseudorandom number" - nothing about what you've said would result in superior randomness. It sounds like you should familiarize yourself with existing theory and techniques before trying to innovate - you're way out of your depth here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While this question has the distinct hallmark of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), the essential point of the question is, how can I get a different value while I'm testing my code as opposed to when I'm actually running the code?

Fundamentally speaking, this can be accomplished in a myriad of ways:

- Mock the service that generates that integer and supply it with whatever integer you want
- Inject the service in design, and replace it with your own while testing, so you can then generate whatever integer you wish
- Hard-coding it (if you *really* had to)

If your question were clearer, you could get an explicit answer on how to solve your problem.  This is just a generic remark to that effect.

Comment: "the essential point of the question is, how can I get a different value while I'm testing my code as opposed to when I'm actually running the code" - that doesn't sound like what the question is asking for to me.

Comment: You're gonna have to squint and ignore the chunk about random numbers, since that's the thing that the OP is trying to solve.  They want random numbers but in some specific way.  Cool, that's doable, and there's a lot of ways to do it depending on how they have their code structured, which is what I *can't* answer.